# Can a body be effected by a force which is not based on a point of the body? ( Principle of transmissibility of force)

Tags: mechanical-engineering

> The principle of transmissibility states that the point of application of a force can be moved anywhere along its line of action without changing the external reaction forces on a rigid body. Any force that has the same magnitude and direction, and which has a point of application somewhere along the same line of action will cause the same acceleration and will result in the same moment. Therefore, the points of application of forces may be moved along the line of action to simplify the analysis of rigid bodies. [Refer](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mechanical_Engineering/Mechanics_Map_(Moore_et_al.)/02%3A_Static_Equilibrium_in_Concurrent_Force_Systems/2.03%3A_Principle_of_Transmissibility#:%7E:text=The%20principle%20of%20transmissibility%20states,forces%20on%20a%20rigid%20body.)
> [image]

In the picture, we can see that the effect of force is the same even if it doesn't pass through the body. How does that make sense?

Comment: [Similar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699891/260477) post here.

Comment: Are you talking about the L-shaped figure? I fail to see the problem. "the effect of force is same even if it doesn't pass through the body"- could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Consider $L$ to be the region of the points which the lamina exists, let $l$ be the line of action of force vector. There are points $x \in (l-L)$ where the force vector can be kept and still the system is equivalent to the original case. The issue with points $x \in (l-L)$ is that they are not even on the lamina, so how could a lamina be effected when a force acts on a point outside it's region of existence?

Comment: The minus denotes set difference.

Comment: Yes, now I understand your question better. In fact, I have the same question as you.  However, in the second picture, the force seems to be acting on the body. The second picture seems to be fine as in the force seems to be passing through the body. Why are you saying that the force doesn't pass through the body?

Comment: The line of the force does, but I am saying the base point $y$ of the force does not need to neccesarily be in $L$@tryingtobeastoic

Comment: If a force acts on a body at a point, do we indicate that by placing the base of the force vector at that point?

Comment: Yes, it's a borrowed idea from differential Geometry I suppose. Look up tangent space at a point of a manifold @tryingtobeastoic

Comment: Your 2nd latest comment is confusing to read after the edit. "I am saying the base point $y$ of the force does not need to necessarily be in $L$" - do you mean does need to necessarilly be in $L$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134942/discussion-between-buraian-and-tryingtobeastoic).

Comment: You might find this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410108/768162) very interesting.

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4408053/768162) and this [article](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/vector5.pdf) could prove to be very helpful to you.

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4411760/768162) might be of great interest to you.

Comment: The answer to your question might be found [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700494/isnt-this-article-using-a-non-standard-way-to-denote-force-vectors?noredirect=1#comment1567574_700494)

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

We know the force is a vector that moves on a straight line (line of action). In space, when the force is acting on a point of a rigid body, in order to maintain the structural equilibrium of the body, there must be an equal but opposite force (reaction) acting on the body along the line of action at the other end ($R = F$), and most importantly - the potential for the rigid body to rotate about any point located within the rigid body and measured perpendicularly from the line of action by a distance $"d"$ is "zero", that is $M_A = F*d - R*d = 0$. Note this is true for $F$ acting on anywhere along the line of action, which proves the "linear transmissibility of force".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A force does not matter where it is applied as long as it has these properties.

It acceleates the body by

$$F=ma$$
it causes the angular acceleration$\alpha$

$$FD= I \alpha$$

- D= distance between force and cm the body
- I= moment of inertia

As we see these condintions are satisfied on both your figures.